# SQL Server split string and access different parts of it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update the url stored in a column.

My columns have values like this:

```
https://www.site.sharepoint.com/sites/test/AB-19-CALL
```

I want to update this URL to:

```
https://www.site.sharepoint.com/sites/test/CALL-AB-19
```

To get the last part which is `AB-19-CALL`, I used the below query

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(urlcompte, LEN(urlcompte) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(urlcompte)) + 2, LEN(urlcompte)), 
    UrlCompte 
FROM 
    tblAccount
```

Now to split and reverse the `AB-19-call` I would again need to use  the entire query above and then select substring using `-`

Is there an easier way to do this?

In C# we can do something like this:

```
urlCompte.Split('-')[2] + urlCompte.Split('-')[0] + urlCompte.Split('-')[1]
```

Is there a way in SQL Server to split the column and access different parts of it?

Comment: If you know that the last part will never have a "." contained in it (e.g. `AB-1.9-CALL`) then you could replace the `-` with `.` and make use of the [parsename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql) function.

Comment: [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) makes things easier if you're running SQL Server 2016 and above.

Answer (score 2):

This would work to split the string parts -

```
DECLARE @txt NVARCHAR(500)= 'https://www.site.sharepoint.com/sites/test/AB-19-CALL';

SELECT value
FROM STRING_SPLIT(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@txt), 1, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@txt))-1)), '-');(substring(reverse(@txt),1,charindex('/',reverse(@txt))-1)),'-')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are so lucky to be using SQL Server 2017 you can use for [string_agg function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/string-aggregation-function-to-concatenate-in-sql-server-2017.aspx) for concatenating splitted string pieced with [SQL string_split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/split-string-function-in-sqlserver-2016.aspx)

Here is the script to change the order of last part in your url

```
declare @url varchar(100) = 'CALL-AB-19'

select 
    string_agg(value,'-') within group (order by rn desc) 
from (
    select 
        value, row_number() over (order by @url) as rn 
    from STRING_SPLIT( @url , '-' )
) t
```

If you want to apply this solution as a set based solution on your table rows with a single SELECT statement, you can execute following SQL

```
select 
    id, string_agg(value,'-') within group (order by rn desc) 
from (
    select 
        id, value, row_number() over (partition by id order by url) as rn 
    from urlList
    cross apply STRING_SPLIT( url , '-' )
) t
group by id
```

I assume, in your table urlList, you have a PK field id

[image]

If you don't use SQL Server 2016 for split function and SQL Server 2017 for string aggregate function, you can search the web for [split string function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx) samples. And using FOR XML Path to concatenate string parts, you can build a solution with the help of CTE expression as follows

```
;with cte as (
    select
        urlList.id,
        urlList.url,
        s.id sid,
        s.val
    from urlList
    cross apply dbo.split(url,'-' ) s
)
SELECT
    distinct
    id,
    STUFF(
        (
        SELECT
            '-' + u.val
        FROM cte as u
        where u.id = cte.id
        Order By sid desc
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, ''
    ) As newurl
FROM cte
```

Please note that the referred split function returns an id named numeric field which shows the order of the splitted piece. So while concatenating I use an "order by" clause on the same field this time in descending order

Answer (score 1):

If someone is using SQL server 2012 or older version then it can be possible by this way:

```
DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(100) = 'https://www.site.sharepoint.com/sites/test/AB-19-CALL'

SELECT TOP 1 dbo.[Reversedata](DATA, '-')
FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.Splitter(@URL, '/') as t) as tt order by Id desc
```

In above code I have used two functions: 
1) Splitter : To split the string (https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql.html)
2) Reversedata: To reverse the data (http://picnicerror.net/development/sql-server/reverse-order-words-string-sql-server-2012-01-16/)

**Splitter:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Splitter]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
GO
```

**Reverse:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_ReverseSequenceOrder] (
@Input nvarchar(200)
,@Delimiter nvarchar(5)
)

RETURNS nvarchar(200)
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @Output nvarchar(200)

WHILE LEN(@Input) > 0
BEGIN
IF CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Input) > 0
BEGIN
SET @Output = SUBSTRING(@Input,0,CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Input)) + @Delimiter + ISNULL(@Output,'')
SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input,CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Input)+1,LEN(@Input))
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @Output = @Input + @Delimiter + ISNULL(@Output,'')
SET @Input = ''
END
END

RETURN SUBSTRING(@Output,0,LEN(@Output))
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is the xml based solution. For SQL Server 2008 and above.

```
DECLARE @url VARCHAR(100) = 'AB-19-CALL'

SELECT MyUrl FROM 
(
    SELECT CAST('<Url><Part>' + REPLACE(@url,'-','</Part><Part>') + '</Part></Url>' AS XML) AS my_Xml 
) t1
CROSS APPLY 
(
     SELECT 
        my_Data.D.value('Part[3]','varchar(50)') + '-' + 
        my_Data.D.value('Part[1]','varchar(50)') + '-' + 
        my_Data.D.value('Part[2]','varchar(50)') AS MyUrl
     FROM t1.my_Xml.nodes('/Url') as my_Data(D)
) t2
```

**Result**

```
MyUrl
----------
CALL-AB-19
```